# How do I pull a comparable date from an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, momentjs

I have an Object of Objects formatted like so:

```
var data = {
             09-29-2017: Array[
                               {jobNumber: "59067", jobState: "FinishedGoods"},
                               {jobNumber: "59068", jobState: "inManufacturing"}
],     
            09-08-2017: Array[
                               {jobNumber: "62155", jobState: "Approved"}]
```

... continued for a lot of dates and anywhere between 0-50 jobNumber and corresponding jobStates per date.

our weeks are set on fridays so every date is a friday and that is all the jobs for the preceding week.

using javascript, jquery, moment.js, or any other suggested Library I'm trying to write a function that I can pass the date from the data object to and return an array with all of the dates that have at least one Job in them that is greater or equal to the closest friday.

So far I've come up with this:

```
function getWeeksWithJobs(){
    var data = getData(); //This is the object of arrays of objects that I'm trying to pull the date from
    var today =  new Date(); 
    today = moment(today).format('MM-DD-YYYY'); 
    var weekRay = []; // this is the array I'm trying to return with just the dates that fit the specifications
    $.each(data, function(index, value){  //in this function index returns the date, and the value returns the array containing the objects.

        if (data[index].length > 0) // this seems to be working fine 
            //I'm just stuck here with how to compare the dates
            //If I use moment(index).format('MM-DD-YYYY') it throws an error
            //If I just use console.log(index) it outputs the date
            // in the right format and everything no punctuation or anything 
            // If I just compare them normally index >= today it just
            // compares the month.
                weekRay.push(index);

    });
    return weekRay;
}
```

My biggest issue is just trying to make the dates comparable, they are both in the same format 'MM-DD-YYYY' but they don't compare. I welcome any advice, thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** 
I found something that works, if I converted the dates into a moment object using today = moment(today, 'MM-DD-YYYY') then I passed them to a function that converts the date to an epochValue:

```
function epochDays(date)
{
date = new Date(date) // and then convert them back into a Date object
return Math.floor(date /day_mSecs);  //const day_mSecs =86400000 
}
```

So I had to take the variables convert them to a moment() object, then from there convert them to a Date object before I could even do much with them.  They were finally comparable and I was able to find which days came after the current date.  Thanks for all your help everybody.

Comment: See the [query](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/) section of the docs, moment has `isAfter`, `isBefore` and `isSame` methods to compare moment objects.

Comment: you could use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) dates, who are comparable and easy to use without converting to a Date object.

Comment: i think it has to be a date string like  `data = { "2017-01-01" : Array[]}` as identifier because of the `-` chars 2017-01-01 without quotes will be tried to calculated, or not?

Comment: @VincenzoC I've tried .isAfter, isBefore, and isSame they just give me errors because they are in the wrong format.

Comment: @NinaScholz How would I convert them? would it be simpler to use moment or to try to use Date()?

Comment: at least, you need some method to find the friday.

Comment: @mtizziani I'm not sure.  Whenever I output them to console, neither of them contain quotes, but I can try stripping them.

Comment: @NinaScholz the array contains nothing but the dates of fridays, I have already filtered everything else out.

Comment: @Jeanze, ok, i understand, so you give a date and you want to get the same or nextfriday with not empty data?

Comment: @NinaScholz pretty much, I am already going through and finding all the dates with at least one job, I just need to set it up to where it starts on the closest Friday, and doesn't show any date before it.

Comment: is the data sorted?

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes it was all sorted by date with SQL as I pulled it from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an even bigger problem because I needed not only to compare dates but also iterate over date ranges (day by day).

My solution was to store dates simply as the number of days from Epoch time, so they are simple integers.

Of course, if you only need to compare dates for sorting purposes, it's not necessary to store them in that format. You can simply rely on a conversion function.

Here a simplified example of what I did:

```
const day_mSecs = 86400000;

function epochDays (date) {
    return Math.floor( // Epoch days (comparable dates).
        new Date(date) / day_mSecs
    );
};

console.log(epochDays('12-25-1995')); // 9488
```

**EDIT:**

After re-reading second @Jeanze comment I noticed that in my rewriting of the slightly more complex function I use to make it simpler (to better fit to this question), I removed by mistake a `(...).valueOf()` over the generated Date object.

...and guessed (even I'm not sure) what could be the reason because previous snipped worked for me but could fail depending on the actual Javascript engine.

That is: `new Date(date)` returns a *Date* object, not a number so when we try to operate it as if it were a  number (`/ day_mSecs`) most javascript engines should try to convert it though `.valueOf()` method if the returned object has it.

So, if the engine is too old and:

- Its *Date* objects doesn't provide a `.valueOf()` method (which is improbable because of [it is specified from very ancient Javascript versions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf)).
- ...or, for some reason, that js engine doesn't try to cast it to ingeger calling `.valueOf()`

...then it will return a *NaN* result as @Jeanze reported.

In the first case, there is an alternative method ([.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)) which does the same. Even it will be necessary to call it explicitly (as, in fact, I did with `.valueOf()` in the function I simplified for this post).

Here is a fixed version of the previous snippet using `.getTime()`:

```
const day_mSecs = 86400000;

function epochDays (date) {
    return Math.floor( // Epoch days (comparable dates).
        (new Date(date)).getTime() / day_mSecs
    );
};

console.log(epochDays('12-25-1995')); // 9488
```

...even, if it works (for engines that fails with the first version such as @Jeanze's one) it would be interesting to check if it also works replacing it by `.valueOf()` (this time explicitly called):

```
        // (new Date(date)).getTime() / day_mSecs
        (new Date(date)).valueOf() / day_mSecs
```

Comment: I tried to implement your function, and what ever variable I run through epochDays(date); just returns NaN.

Comment: I worked with it a little bit and if I converted them to a moment date using moment(today, 'MM-DD-YYYY' then passed them to epochDays and I changed epochDays just a little bit I added date = new Date(date); then just changed the next line to return Math.floor(date/ day_mSecs); and it worked just fine. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What values are you trying. The value in the console.log of my example works for you? I tested it in Node v6.10.2 and the output is what I put in last comment (9488).

Comment: Ok then. (We both posted at the same time). I'm glad you could manage it. ;-)

Comment: Thanks you, I had to convert the variables to a moment() object then a Date object but then they were finally comparable.

Comment: @Jeanze: You probably don't need to use moment() as you said. Please, see my edit. You probably could get rid of the NaN error by explicit *.valueOf()* or, at least, by *.getTime()* call.

Answer (score 4):

Please try the below code to compare the date.

```
var today =  new Date();
today.setHours(0,0,0,0);

$.each(data, function(index, value){

  if (data[index].length > 0){

    // if index returns the date than
    var newIndex = new Date(index);
    newIndex .setHours(0,0,0,0);

    // now compare the both dates

    if(newIndex >= today)
    {
      // TO DO
    }


    weekRay.push(index);
  }
});
```

Comment: Its throwing an error saying "index.setHours is not a function".

Comment: @Jeanze, I just take a new date variable within a loop and assign index to it. Please try with it.

Comment: I figured it out, thank you for your help though, I figured out I had to convert the date variable to a moment() object by saying moment(date, 'MM-DD-YYYY') then I had to convert it to a date object by saying : date = new Date(date);  then I compared it from there and I could tell which date came first.  I edited the question with the solution, thanks again for the help though.

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide format argument when passing in non standard date strings to `moment()`:

Example:

```
moment("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY");
```

Comment: so would I just use     moment(index, 'MM-DD-YYYY') and is that any different then adding moment(index).format('MM-DD-YYYY')? because I've tried the second approach and it still gives me errors.

Comment: Yes is different.  The `format()` function is used to return a string from a moment date object. But you need a valid object first

Comment: It's giving me this error:   "Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release.   It looks like its still not in the right format.

Comment: I can get it working fine if I hard code the date, but I need it to be dynamic and for some reason, I can't get my variable pulled from my object to parse correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ISO dates, because you can copmpare the strings directly without converting or using other methods.

In this proposal, the given keys are iterated and checked. All dates in the past or empty arrays are ignored. The result is made with a check, if the actual date is smaller than the date from the iteration.

This works for unsorted keys.

```js
var data = {
        '2017-09-29': [{ jobNumber: "59067", jobState: "FinishedGoods" }, { jobNumber: "59068", jobState: "inManufacturing" }],
        '2017-09-22': [{ jobNumber: "5yy67", jobState: "FinishedGoods" }, { jobNumber: "5yy68", jobState: "inManufacturing" }],
        '2017-09-15': [],
        '2017-09-08': [{ jobNumber: "62155", jobState: "Approved" }],
    },
    date = '2017-09-14',
    result = Object.keys(data).reduce(function (r, k, i) {
        if (!data[k].length || k < date) {
            return r;
        }
        return !r || k < r ? k : r;
    }, '');

console.log(result);
```

For descending sorted keys, you could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and exit early.

```js
var data = {
        '2017-09-29': [{ jobNumber: "59067", jobState: "FinishedGoods" }, { jobNumber: "59068", jobState: "inManufacturing" }],
        '2017-09-22': [{ jobNumber: "5yy67", jobState: "FinishedGoods" }, { jobNumber: "5yy68", jobState: "inManufacturing" }],
        '2017-09-15': [],
        '2017-09-08': [{ jobNumber: "62155", jobState: "Approved" }],
    },
    date = '2017-09-14',
    key,
    result = Object.keys(data).reduce(function (r, k, i) {
        if (k < date) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!data[k].length) {
            return;
        }
        if (!key || k < key) {
            key = k;
        }
    }, '');

console.log(key);
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand, is the date variable supposed to be the date of today, or is it representing the date being passed in?

Comment: it is the given date. maybe i do not understand the question.

Comment: I apologize if I'm not being clear enough,  I was just attempting to implement your solution as a separate function. I need to be able to get the date of the day the program is being run by either Date.now, moment(), or something else.  Then I need to be able to run the data object through a function and then the function returns an array or object with just the dates that have at least one job, that is either the current week or in the future.

Comment: for the actual date, you could take the date from the `Date` object with `(new Date).toISOString().slice(0, 10)`